# Should I create one db table or two?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a db table with thousands of books (title, year, writer etc.). The users can add the books they have read to a list. I want to give them the ability to add books of they own if they're not available in the db., and they will available for that user only. Should I create a new table, or just add their books to the main table with a "is_custom" and "user_id" columns? The second way seems much easier for me to manage (in terms of search for example, joining the two table seems stupid..), but i'm asking since both (my books and the users books) would become pretty large..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the best way is to use one table for one entity. So variant 1.
'Users' - another table through a table of links (many to many). Your own books are owned to a predefined constant user (better, or without link to user).

In OOP databases you could use the parent table and two childs. But at first look your situation doesn't requere even that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd design for simplicity and maintainability first, and only introduce performance improvements once you know you have a problem.

"Pretty large" means different things to different people - but if you have to solve that problem, you'll probably have to solve it twice if you split the data across two tables, or - possibly even worse - have a different solution for managing the "books" table than for the "userBooks" table.